# Replace double http:// or https://

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox with a pre-value of "http://".

Sometimes people paste the entire link and forget to remove the preset value, getting a `http://http://`.

I figured out how to replace it.

However, I'm trying to write something that converts this way:
`http://http://` -> `http://` and
`http://https://` -> `https://`

I wrote that and for `https://` it gives an error. For `http://` simply nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function replacehttp() {

    var iurl = document.getElementById('url').value;

    if (iurl.substring(0, 15) == 'http://https://') {

        var surl = iurl.replace('http://https://', 'https://').
        document.getElementById('url').value = surl;
        generate();

    } else if (iurl.substring(0, 14) == 'http://https://') {
        var ourl = iurl.replace('http://http://', 'http://');
        document.getElementById('url').value = ourl;
        generate();
    }
}
```

PS: the generate() is other function I want to call in both scenarios

Comment: Would it be easier to not include the pre-populated `http://` and add it on if missing/needed?

Comment: Why not remove the placeholder, or use the attribute `placeholder` to have the browser do it for you automatically.

Comment: You should use the placeholder attribute and add the `http://` only if missing: `<input type="text" placeholder="http://" />`

Comment: I know I can use the `placeholder`, but in this case I need to use the `value`.

My textbox has a `http://` value. Let's say that someone pastes a link, and it gets `http://http://www.google.pt`. I want it to convert to `http://www.google.pt`. The same thing for `https://` links

Comment: @user2699627: Again with the 'need'. You don't 'need' to do anything, you're free to do whatever the hell you want. What can possibly cause a requirement like that? This is, by definition, the job of a placeholder, and not a value. `value=` should be set for a **default** value, the value that would be submitted if the user passes on the input.

Comment: Yes, I want... No need, of course. My english is not the best. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is obviously wrong - it should be:

```
} else if (iurl.substring(0, 14) == 'http://http://') {
//                                             ^ not https
```

A simpler alternative:

```
function replacehttp() {
    var iurl = document.getElementById('url').value;
    iurl = iurl.replace(/^http:\/\/(https?:\/\/)/, '$1');
    document.getElementById('url').value = iurl ;
    generate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @kobi. It was my fault copying the code (the one I saved doesn't have that wrong https).

Comment: @user2699627 - then you need to post your actual code, or it is very difficult to help you `:)`

Comment: Thanks @Kobi, this helped me. You've missed a `/`, but I figured out. 

Regards!

Answer (score 4):

I would use a regular expression to do that:

```
iurl = iurl.replace(/^http:\/\/(https?:\/\/)/, "$1");
```

If you are unfamiliar with regex you can google it, but briefly:

Expression between `/ ... /` is a regular expression literal.

`^` matches the start of the string

`/` have to be escaped with `\/`, so the expression really is `^http://(https?://)`

`?` means that the previous char (i.e. `s`) is optional.

`()` are used to capture the value that matched (i.e. either `http://` or `https://`).

`$1` is a special value meaning: replace with the first captured group.

Comment: Missed your answer and wrote exactly the same thing. +1 for being quicker `:)`. I'd also add the `/i` flag, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Your function has some errors, use this:

> function replacehttp() {
>
> ```
>         var iurl = document.getElementById('url').value;
>
>         if (iurl.substring(0, 15) == 'http://https://') {
>             alert('123');
>             var surl = iurl.replace('http://https://', 'https://');
>             document.getElementById('url').value = surl;
>             generate();
>         }
>         else if (iurl.substring(0, 14) == 'http://http://') {
>             var ourl = iurl.replace('http://http://', 'http://');
>             document.getElementById('url').value = ourl;
>             generate();
>         }
>         return false;
>     }
> ```

with this: `<input type="submit" onclick="return replacehttp()" />`

after this line `var surl = iurl.replace('http://https://', 'https://').` there is the `.` and not this `;`